# Mysql custom where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

**My table is :**

[image: my table]

I want to select records who all are fail(result=0) but except who has same course_id result is 1.

For example look my table there are two rows have result=0 but student_id=1 has another row with result=1 so i want skip this record.

Sorry for confusing you.I hope my expecting output explains clearly what I want.

**Expecting output is :**

2   |   1 |   0

Comment: clarify what you mean by `but ignore who has same course_id result is 1.`

Comment: For example look my table there are two rows have result=0 but student_id=1 has another row with result=1 so i want skip this record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT student_id, course_id, result FROM tbl WHERE result = 0 
AND student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM table WHERE result =1 
                                      and course_id = tbl.course_id )
```

Above we are selecting all records that have a `result =0` only if the student_id and course_id is not found in the sub query with a `result=1`

Comment: Need to consider course_id too because one student_id has multiple course_id with different results(1 or 0)

Comment: See my updated answer. All that was needed was adding course_id = tbl.course_id to the where clause of the sub query